# How to retrieve stats in JSON file and build a bar chart with ChartJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, chart.js

I'm trying to store data (statistics) in JSON file everyday. 
To do that I'm using [json-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-file) in my NodeJS app. I'm using Nunjucks, so I can easily pass values from server side to client side.

My code work well, each day, a new field is created in stats.json. So now I have this JSON :

```
{
  "4/5/2017":5,
  "5/5/2017":3
  ...
}
```

If json-file find a `date == date now` in the JSON file, I add 1 to the counter. If not a new field with the new date is created.
The code to do that :

```
var json_result_date_visits

function getDate() {
  dateNow = moment().format('l')
}

if (file.get(dateNow)) {

  json_result_date_visits = file.get(dateNow)
  file.set(dateNow, json_result_date_visits+1)
  json_result_date_visits = 0
  file.writeSync()

} else {

  file.set(dateNow, 1)
  file.writeSync()

}
```

The question is how to handle these values, my objective is to create a bar chart with ChartJS and take the last 20 days to build it. (Other days will be shown in a simple table).
I can't imagine how to work with this type of data. On chartjs (client side) how to put in the labels array the dates, and for each labels (so data[] with chartjs) apply the number of visit this day.

I already try to play with object in my JSON to order the date, like this :

`{visits_date: {date:[thedate: count_visit]}}`

But I don't know how to handle this type of data.

I also try to get all values from all date using a regex.

`var date_visits_analytics = file.get(/^\d+\/\d+\/\d+$/)`

I believe json-file will find all date and give me each value, but it seems to not work

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your JSON file can express any javascript object or hierarchy of objects.  I would suggest thinking about the data structures a bit more.  Objects are unsorted.  Arrays have an ordering, and a sort function.  Eventually to build your chart it will be necessary to order the dates, so if you use the posted object key:value format you eventually must extract all the keys and values into an array and sort them to get the array inputs to a plotting function. Also, comparing date with today is easier if they are in sort order.

Comment: I already try to modify the structure of my JSON.
{visits_date: {date:[thedate: count_visit]}} but I don't know how to change the date key to avoid multiple 'date' key

Comment: Well, what you seem to be asking is how to move JSON data from the server to the browser. The usual way is to do an ajax request in the javascript app that runs on the browser, to ask the server to send the data.  That requires that either (i) the server is running some customized code (e.g. in nodejs, php, etc.) that will fetch the desired data when the browser side code sends it a request; or (ii) you have some cron job or other server-side task that copies the json files to a directory on your web server so that a request by the browser to the web server will "naturally" retrieve the data.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I'm using Nunjucks. On my JSON file I also have a 'total_visits', everytime a visitor reach '/' route, it add +1 (without day distinction). After that, always with json-file, I write `var total_visits_analytics = file.get("total_visits")`, and then the `res.render(my_view, {total_visits: total_visits_analytics})`. After that in my template I simply use `{{ total_visits }}`. So know how to get each days with each number of visits. Sort them. I try to use regex to retrieve all days in JSON : `var date_visits_analytics = file.get(/^\d+\/\d+\/\d+$/)`, but it don't work...

Comment: Well, I need to run.  So what you could do, is click the small "edit" link underneath your post, and try to edit in that last comment into the main body of your question, maybe with some code.  People are more willing to answer when they see all that.

Comment: I editing my first post, ask me if you want more informations